# WCF Read stream changes the behaviour of a WebFaultException

Tags: wcf

We have the following web method:

```
        public void RawData(string dataItemName, Stream sourceStream)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sourceStream);
            {
                string data = reader.ReadToEnd();

                throw new WebFaultException<string>("error", System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
```

and is defined as follows:

```
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate= "RawData/{dataItemName}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(LoginFaultInfo))]
        [FaultContract(typeof(SecurityFaultInfo))]
        [FaultContract(typeof(RequestFaultInfo))]
        [Description("Sets data for the specified item")]
        void RawData(string dataItemName, Stream dataStream);
```

This correctly generates the exception in the client.

However, if this code is changed as follows:

```
        public void RawData(string dataItemName, Stream sourceStream)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sourceStream))
            {
                string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
               
            throw new WebFaultException<string>("error", System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
```

Then the client gets a 202 Accepted Status rather than a fault exception.

Does anyone know why this is the case? Reading and disposing of the stream has changed the behaviour somehow,

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "`using`" in WCF Client.
You can check Microsoft documentation for instructions.
[Close and Abort release resources safely when network connections have dropped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/use-close-abort-release-wcf-client-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> The C# "using" statement results in a call to Dispose(). This is the
> same as Close(), which may throw exceptions when a network error
> occurs. Because the call to Dispose() happens implicitly at the
> closing brace of the "using" block, this source of exceptions is
> likely to go unnoticed both by people writing the code and reading the
> code. This represents a potential source of application errors.

I think you can use the Microsoft recommended way of handling WCF client calls.
For more detail see: [Expected Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/expected-exceptions?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: The using statement is not being used on the client side - it is being done on the server side. Also I am not getting an exception - I am getting a 202 Accepted response.

Comment: Just to confirm the stream is being passed to the server - not read from the server.

Comment: The `202 Accepted response` status code indicates that the request has been accepted for processing, but processing has not yet completed.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202

Comment: You can turn on Trace and Message Logging in the service to investigate how operations are performed on the server.